# How to highlight some words in a non-readonly field in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a "models.TextField" which is editable in Admin. How can I highlight certain words in it such that when someone opens admin for this model those words are highlighted. In addition, when you change the field value, I want those highlights (probably markdowns in the text) not to be considered when saving the model.

Comment: A HTML textarea won't work, you'll need some WYSWIG kind of widget.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more or send me a link?